# Java мультипроект

Tags: java, mvc, spring, maven

проект написан и работает, но вопрос по структуре. следуещее задание вопрос по 13 пункту.

> Посмотрите пожалуйста пункт 13 задания, подразумевалось, что
>   мультипроект должен состоять из множества функционально независимых
>   модулей (по логическим слоям), а не из двух подпроектов.
>
> В Вашем случае не получится не пересобирая проект заменить реализацию
>   например слоя dao на другую реализацию.

подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

1. Установить Tomcat.
2. База данных (БД): MySQL, H2, HSQLDB (для тестов использовать «In-memory database mode»).
3. Установить подключение к БД.
4. В БД необходимо создать две таблицы: Отделы и Сотрудники.
5. БД должна заполняться тестовыми данными.
6. Для отделов хранить название отдела.
7. Для сотрудников хранить: отдел, ФИО сотрудника, дату его рождения и его зарплату.
8. Дополнительные фреймворки Spring, MyBatis (если нужен).
9. Выбрать на свое усмотрение вариант доступа к БД: Spring JDBC или MyBatis реализация.
10. Написать (и уметь публиковать «руками» на сервер Tomcat) Web-сервис (RESTful или JAX-WS) для доступа к данным, который будет выбирать данные из БД и сохранять/изменять/удалять данные в БД.
11. Написать (и так же уметь публиковать «руками» на сервер Tomcat) простое Web-приложение для работы с отделами и сотрудниками отделов (технологии для реализации пользовательского интерфейса: Struts, Spring MVC). Данное приложение для работы с БД должно использовать Web-сервис указанный выше (п.10).
12. Web - приложение должно позволять:

    - посмотреть список отделов и среднюю зарплату (рассчитывается автоматически) по этим отделам (первая списочная форма);
    - список сотрудников в отделах с указанием зарплаты для каждого сотрудника  и полем поиска для поиска сотрудников родившихся в определенную дату или в период между датами (вторая списочная форма);
    - изменять (добавлять/редактировать/удалять) вышеуказанные данные.
13. Структура проекта: мультипроект с четким разделением на слои и покрытием тестами на каждом уровне:

    ```
    Пример структуры проекта:
    department-app
     |-model
     |-dao
     |-service
     |-rest
     |-web-app
    ```
14. Проект ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО собирать либо с помощью Maven либо- Gradle.
15. Проект ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должен собираться из командной строки.
16. Результат сборки приложения - 2 WAR файла:

    WAR файл для приложения REST-service;

    - model
    - dao
    - services < - > rest

    WAR файл для приложения c WEB – интерфейсом.

    - model
    - services < - > rest
    - web

Answer (score 3):

> Структура проекта: мультипроект с четким разделением на слои и покрытием тестами на каждом уровне: Пример структуры проекта: department-app |-model |-dao |-service |-rest |-web-app

Это значит, что вам нужно почитать про [мультимодульные maven-проекты](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). И разнести код по модулям. Модели - отдельный jar, DAO - отдельный, и.т.д.

Итоговый war будет содержать все модули приложения как библиотки в WEB-INF/lib